# Go: How to resolve dependency for structs passing between two packages as params?

Tags: go, dependencies

Don’t know what’s the best practice to structure this so I don’t have cyclic dependency, I have a `user` package which exposes `UserService` which takes a store because it needs to access database, but it also has some structs

```golang
package user

type UserParams struct {
    Client             util.HTTPExecutor
    Store              store.Store
    ...
}

func NewUserService(params *UserServiceParams) *UserService {...}


type User struct {
    ID               int32        `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Name             string       `db:"name" json:"name"`
}
```

At the same time I have a store package which has an interface takes some user structs and save into the database.

```golang
package store

type Store interface {
  UpdateUser(ctx context.Context, u *user.User) error
}
```

Does it make more sense to

1. Move `User` struct into store package (latter might end up a lot of those structs for different product components)
2. Move `User` struct into a separate common package so both packages have access to it
3. Move `User` struct into a package `userstruct` under `user` package

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this question is slightly subjective because it depends largely on your project and how your project lays out. That being said, here is what I would do if I were you.

Consider adding a `types` package. A `types` package would rarely be dependent on anything else, but everything would be dependent on the `types` package. Then both your `store` and `services` packages could import the `types` package without any concern for cyclical dependencies.

*Arrows denote a dependency/import*

[image]

Comment: Alternately, if the `User` and `Store` types are really that tightly coupled, perhaps they belong in the same package. Or, perhaps `user` and `userservice` should be separate packages. (“`types`” is usually a pretty awkward package boundary — most packages naturally define a type or two. See https://go.dev/blog/package-names.)